# Discord Bot not working at ```on_member_join``` and ```on_member_remove``` event

Tags: python, discord.py

I just started developing discord bots in python, but I have a problem. When I run my bot with the `client.run("token")` command, my `@client.event` events are not working. My code is:

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online!")

@client.event 
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="welcome")
    await channel.send("**{}** just joined the server!".format(member.mention))

@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")

client.run(token)
```

If someone joins my server it seems like my bot is not triggering. I don't know what the problem is! My bot does respond to messages, so the `on_message` event works.

I hope someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed it! What I did is enabling intents in the Dev portal of discord in bot applications. Then I added this lines to my code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
```

Then it worked!